# how to Using svg in iconlayer of deck.gl

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, deck.gl

my test code

```
     const layer = 
    new IconLayer({
      id: 'icon-layer',
      data,
      getIcon: d=> ({data : 'data/test.svg', width:128, height:128}),
      getSize: d => Math.max(2, Math.min(d.contributions / 1000 * 25, 25)),
      pickable: true,
      sizeScale: 15,
      getPosition: d => [127.14467,31.39953]
    });
```

I got a error.

```
icon-manager.js:366 DOMException: The source image cannot be decoded.
```

how to Using svg in iconlayer of deck.gl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API reference](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/icon-layer/) the returned object of the `getIcon` callback must contain a `url` property. From the documentation:

```
getIcon: d => ({
  url: d.avatar_url,
  width: 128,
  height: 128,
  anchorY: 128
}),
```

In your example you need to rename the `url` property to `data`.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your own svg to deck.gl, it doesn't have to be just a url.

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69123265/14954503

Answer (score 0):

I checked svg file.
All languages ​​except English and numbers in the svg file must not be included.
ex : korean, Japanese...
If it is in English only, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the definition of the `getIcon` attribute with the following:

```js
getIcon: d => ({url : 'ICON_URL', width:128, height:128})
```