# How to render custom svg in IconLayer of Deck.gl

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl, deck.gl

i am trying to render a custom svg in iconLayer when a particular condition is met, from this example, https://deck.gl/gallery/icon-layer my getIcon option is

```
getIcon: (d) => ({
      url: './glow.svg',
      width: 128,
      height: 128
    }),
```

I think the url is meant to be the path to the image i want to render
However, nothing is been shown on the map.

the full component is

```
import { IconLayer } from "@deck.gl/layers";
import icons from "../assets/images/monsoon_icons.png";

const COLORS = {
  ...colors
};

const ICON_MAPPING = {
  circle: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70, mask: true },
  rectangle: { x: 70, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70, mask: true },
  triangle: { x: 140, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70, mask: true },
  star: { x: 210, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70, mask: true },
};

export const RenderLayers = (props) => {
  let { data } = props;

  if(props.isSaved) {
    return [
      new IconLayer({
        ...other icon props
        // iconMapping: ICON_MAPPING,
        getIcon: (d) => ({
          url: './glow.svg',
          width: 128,
          height: 128
        }),
       ...other icon props,
      }),
  
      new IconLayer({
         ...other icon props
        // iconMapping: ICON_MAPPING,
        getIcon: (d) => ({
          url: './glow.svg',
          width: 128,
          height: 128
        }),
       ...other icon props,
      }),
    ];
  };

  if (!data?.length) {
    console.log("NO DATA TO MAP");
    return;
  };

  return [
    new IconLayer({
      ...normal icon layer props
      })
  ];
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would need to [convert your svg to data URLs](https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/loading-data#example-use-image-from-a-programmatically-generated-svg-string).

Following the official deck.gl example:

```
import yourSvg from 'whatever/path';

function svgToDataURL(svg) {
  return `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(svg)}`;
}

new IconLayer({
  getIcon: () => ({
    url: svgToDataURL(yourSvg),
    width: 24,
    height: 24
  }),
})
```

Also, you can check **a full working example** [here](https://codepen.io/AdriSolid/pen/KKqWNMr?editors=1010).

Cheers!